# Ordenar Matrices en Python

Tags: python, numpy

Tengo la siguiente matriz: `[[0. 1.] [1. 4.] [-1.  6.] [ 2. -5.]]` y quiero que como resultado me de: `[[-1.  6.] [0. 1.] [1. 4.] [ 2. -5.]]`, el problema es que al utilizar el comando sort() de numpy me cambia las posiciones de ambas columnas individualmete: `[[-1. -5.] [0. 1.] [1. 4.] [2. 6.]]`

Comment: Te propongo como idea crear una variable temporal donde guardes el contenido del la primera fila por ejemplo, para poder modificar la primera fila por la que quieres colocar en esa posicion, y luego utilizar la variable temporal para colocar al fila perdida en el lugar deseado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo intentare

Answer (score 2):

El comando que comentas `numpy.sort` tiene el argumento `axis`, que le indica a la función la dimensión sobre la que quieres ordenar. Por defecto este valor es -1 (última dimensión). En la documentación puedes leer más acerca de cómo usar la función.

En resumen, lo que tu quieres es ordenar la matriz dando prioridad a la primera dimensión, de forma que:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([
    [0, 1],
    [1, 4],
    [-1, 6],
    [2, -5]
])

np.sort(x, axis=0) # [[-1, -5], [0, 1], [1, 4], [2, 6]]
```

Comment: El problema es que los datos son pares ordenados para coordenadas en un plano, por eso necesito que se queden juntos para no variar dichas coordenadas